# SQL COMPUTED COLUMN SPECIFICATION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can somebody please help me with my computed specification formula. I can't make it work. Below is the idea i'm implementing. Thank you.

```
CASE WHEN REASONFORNOE10 IS NULL THEN TOT_SCORE = [q_1]+[q_2]+[q_3]+[q_4]+[q_5]+[q_6]+[q_7]+[q_8]+[q_9]+[q_010] 
 WHEN REASONFORNOE10 IS NOT NULL THEN TOT_SCORE = '99' 
 ELSE '' END
```

Comment: "I can't make it work" is not a problem description. What are you trying to accomplish, and what is wrong with your current attempt?

Comment: Try this:
TOT_SCORE=CASE WHEN REASONFORNOE10 IS NULL THEN  [q_1]+[q_2]+[q_3]+[q_4]+[q_5]+[q_6]+[q_7]+[q_8]+[q_9]+[q_010] 
 WHEN REASONFORNOE10 IS NOT NULL THEN '99' 
 ELSE '' END

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is that when you fill the [REASONFORNOE10] column then the [TOT_SCORE] will automatically filled with '99' but when leave [REASONFORNOE10] then fill in [q_1] ..[q_010] then it will computer whatever value you put in it.

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2012 by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. This may help you:

If you want the result as a string value, follow this:

```
 SELECT TOT_SCORE=CASE WHEN REASONFORNOE10 IS NULL THEN CAST([q_1]+[q_2]+[q_3]+[q_4]+[q_5]+[q_6]+[q_7]+[q_8]+[q_9]+[q_010] AS VARCHAR)
     WHEN REASONFORNOE10 IS NOT NULL THEN '99' 
     ELSE '' END
```

Otherwise you want numeric values, try this:

```
   SELECT TOT_SCORE=CASE WHEN REASONFORNOE10 IS NULL THEN [q_1]+[q_2]+[q_3]+[q_4]+[q_5]+[q_6]+[q_7]+[q_8]+[q_9]+[q_010]
     WHEN REASONFORNOE10 IS NOT NULL THEN 99
     ELSE 0 END
```